# User Control in JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls

I am having User Control in Jquery Dialog. When Page is loading for the first, User Control page load event is firing. On dialog popup, page load is not firing and eventually Button click events are not firing. Below is my Jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#imgSearch").click(function (e) {
             $("#divSearch").dialog({
                 open: function() {
                     $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                     .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                     .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");                        
                 },
                 title: "Search Employee",
                 modal:true,
                 width: 600,
                 height: 400
             });                 
             e.preventDefault();               
         });
     });
```

Comment: Which click event is not firing ?

Comment: Page_Load and button click. No event is firing.

Comment: It's seems that is working i removed the open function because i'm not sure what are you trying to do let me know if i can help you in some way http://jsfiddle.net/RXUr7/

Comment: Hi, Place a button in user control beside textbox. Try to fire the click event of the button. Popup is working for me but the events on the popup are not working.

Comment: Like this ?http://jsfiddle.net/RXUr7/1/

Comment: Yes, It is working because of you are using Click function using Jquery. I want to post back and hit the code behind.